# How to enable javascript syntax checking in VS2012?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

How do I setup VS2012 to catch javascript syntax errors?  I've been using http://www.javascriptlint.com/ to check my javascript.  Is there an easier way in VS2012?

Comment: Are you asking for something like IntelliSense for javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that there is a JSLint plugin for VS2012

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1a417c37-4d6f-43ca-b753-6ea6eb5041fd

Answer (score 3):

The [Web Essentials extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) can do this using JSHint.

http://vswebessentials.com/features/javascript